# Create an instance given pointer type in template

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to call the constructor of a class, given the pointer-type of that class type as the template parameter?

```
MyClass<AnotherClass*>  => how to call the default constructor of AnotherClass in MyClass?
```

This one does obviously not work (doesnt compile), because in `GetNew` the `new T` and the return type T don't fit together. What would be needed is some kind of "type dereferencing" to come to the class type, given the pointer type.

```
class AnotherClass
{};

template <class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    // this does obviously not compile
    virtual T GetNew()
    {
        return new T; // how let T be AnotherClass* and to create an AnotherClass instance here?
    }

};

int main()
{
    // this does not compile:
    MyClass<AnotherClass*> tmp; // here, AnotherClass is **pointer** type
    AnotherClass* a = tmp.GetNew();

}
```

A workaround would be to use the class type as the template parameter and use poiter types as return types. But this changes the interface, so I would still like a solution to pointer template type.

```
class AnotherClass
{};

template <class T>
class MyClass2
{
public:
    virtual T* GetNew()
    {
        return new T;
    }

};

int main()
{
    // this does work:
    MyClass2<AnotherClass> tmp2; // here, AnotherClass is **not** pointer type
    AnotherClass* b = tmp2.GetNew();
}
```

Another workaround could be to use a factory or similar, but I would like to use the default constructor without additional helping structures.

Comment: Your "workaround" makes more sense. Why do you need `T` to be a pointer? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: If you must *deference* a pointer type, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer

Comment: Also note that your workaround doesn't really change the interface. `GetNew` still returns a pointer to a `AnotherClass` in both your examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::remove_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) to get the type pointed to.

> Provides the member typedef type which is the type pointed to by T, or, if T is not a pointer, then type is the same as T.

E.g.

```
virtual T GetNew()
{
    return new std::remove_pointer_t<T>;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much (to @nimrod too, who was a bit faster by commenting)! Is this equivalent to `return new std::remove_pointer<T>::type;` ?

Comment: @Micka Yes they're the same. You might need to add `typename` like `return new typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type;` (before c++20).

Answer (score 1):

If you require the parameter to `MyClass` to be a pointer, you can specialise it for pointers and leave it undefined for other types

```
template<typename>
class MyClass;

template<typename T>
class MyClass<T*>
{
public:
    virtual T* GetNew()
    {
        return new T;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // MyClass2<AnotherClass> tmp1; // compile error
    MyClass2<AnotherClass *> tmp2; // fine
    AnotherClass* b = tmp2.GetNew(); // GetNew returns the exact type parameter
}
```

Comment: nice, I didn't know that. Looks even better suited for my situation!